# Inserting data into MySQL while looping over a result set

Tags: mysql, php

How can I execute insert queries while retrieving data from database?

I mean that after running a select query where I am retrieving data using a `while` loop, I also want to insert some fields into another table.
I want to execute inserts forcefully in PHP code.

I tried:

```
$firstview=mysql_query("insert into kadam_firstview(jobtype,jobname,admin_id,date,datetime)values('".$trial."','".$jobname."','".$adminid."','".$time."','".$date."')");
$firstview.execute();
```

But it doesn't work.
i want to run upper query inside select query as i am getting data  from select query at that same time i want to save those data inside another table but query giving error which is mentioned above

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't a problem description. Please [edit] your question to include a description of exactly what "doesn't work" means. Add exact error messages for example, or describe exactly what is happening and what you expected instead.

Comment: Please share you `errors`

Comment: i want to run insert query which should be executed inside select query as i retrieve data through select query at the same time i want to save those retrieve entries into another table

Comment: There is still no description of the error in your question. Please edit again and include the exact error message. And please read about SQL injection and change your code to use bind variables/parameters.

Comment: Can you rewrite your logic into a single SQL statement of the form `insert into table(columns) select ...`?

Answer (score 3):

I think your question is more for php developer then for dba.

Anyway if I understand you correctly you would like to select a record set from a table and insert this values (or modified one) into another table?

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli("host", "username", "password", "databasename");
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table_name");

while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
  $trail = $row->trail;
  $jobname = $row->jobname;
  $adminid = 25;
  $time = $row->time;
  $date = $row->date;
  $query = "insert into kadam_firstview(jobtype,jobname,admin_id,date,datetime) values('".$db->escape_string($trial)."','".$db->escape_string($jobname)."','".$db->escape_string($adminid)."','".$db->escape_string($time)."','".$db->escape_string($date)."')";
  $db->query($query);
}
```

this will copy the rows from the table "table_name" into the table "kadam_firstview" and set the adminid to 25.

http://php.itronic.at/manual/en/class.mysqli.php